# How to disable Search (enter and button) if it's empty or contains only spaces?

Tags: jquery

How to disable Search form (input, enter, button) if it's empty or contains only white spaces?

Example code

```
<form id="example_form" class="example_form">
  <input class="form_input" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I have tried this jQuery code but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form_input').keyup(function() {
  
      var empty = false;
      $('.form_input').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
              empty = true;
          }
      });                   
  
      if (empty) {
          $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
          $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
      }                
    });
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please include the JavaScript or jQuery that you have tried to use or that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.isEmpty = function() {
    return $(this).val() == "" ? true : false;
  }

  $("#example_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var valid = true;
    $(".form_input").each(function(i, el) {
      valid = valid && !$(el).isEmtpy();
    });
    return valid;
  });

  $("#example_form .form_input").keyup(function() {
    $("#example_form button[type='submit']").prop("disabled", $(this).isEmpty());
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="example_form" class="example_form">
  <input class="form_input" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  <button type="submit" disabled="true"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

This does a few small thing. I have created a small Function to check if an Element is "empty", by checking the Value.

Using Submit callback, we can prevent the form from being submitted by using `event.preventDefault()`. We can then check each of the fields and if they are not empty, we can return `true` to continue submitting the form or `false` to prevent it.

Comment: It's not working. After I type text button is still disabled.

Comment: @RootElem I am unable to replicate that with the example I posted. This would suggest there is some other element that is unique about your code that is not replicated here. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example